# Efficient to Sequence - do you have to discard cards first?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

The Efficient to Sequence positive mutation allows a disease to be `cured as soon as one player discards the necessary number of cards`

My question is, what happens if a player draws their eight card? Would they have to immediately discard a card before being allowed to cure, or can they cure immediately and keep them card they drew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to discard first. From the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1470601/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden-each-month-hidden-sep):

> If we have the 2nd beneficial mutation, exactly when can we discover the cure?
>   You can do it out of turn, but you can’t so it halfway through an epidemic. It’s also worth noting when drawing player cards, you’ll have to discard down to hand size before curing.